# Filter by matchpatern"ANY" in a spreadsheet [google-apps-script]

Tags: google-apps-script

i am new(bi) to google apps script and i have some problems !

I am looking for filter a spreadsheet cell where there is differents categories : for exemple

1 Environment
2 Environment, Business
3 Business, Work, Environment, Tourism

i have tryed to use the StringFilter tool with a MatchType(ANY) but the search only returns the first word of the cell.For example the search 'Business' will not find 'Business' in the cell "Environment , Business" . My code:

```
     var categoryFilter = Charts.newStringFilter()
   .setFilterColumnIndex(5)
   .setMatchType(Charts.MatchType.ANY)
   .build();
```

My first objective was to use the newCategoryFilter tool but i couldn't use the MatchType Filter, and the result was bad categories like "Business, Work, Environment, Tourism" in the listBox.And my first code looked like this :

```
     var themeFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter()
  .setFilterColumnLabel("Categories"
  .build();
```

I didnt find a solution yet so i hope you gonna help me :) ! thanks in advance.

Timothée.

Comment: You use the Charts API only to build charts such as pie charts, line graphs etc. To me it looks like that is not what you want to do. But you rather want to have a spreadsheet functionality to filter from a particular column. Can you say where you want to display this filtered information ?

Answer (score 0):

I did some tests, and this looks like a bug in the Charts service. Please file an issue on the Apps Script [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).