# setMatchType(Charts.MatchType.ANY) don't work ? Create my filter to show spreedsheet'data on a google site

Tags: google-apps-script

**hi,first of all sorry for my bad english and i hope u will understand my problems, i want to show data from a spreadsheet on a google site. Actually i put data from spreadsheet in a "newDataTable" and it works well.**

```
    var docOrganismesPubliques =     SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXXXXXSpreadsheetKeyXXXXXXX"); // key du document : "OpenData Organisme Public"    
  var docOpenDataEnFrance = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXXXXXSpreadsheetKeyXXXXXXX"); // key du document : "OpenData en France"

  var docs = new Array();
  docs[0] = docOpenDataEnFrance;
  docs[1] = docOrganismesPubliques;


  var enTetesCrees = false;
  for(var m=0; m <docs.length; m++) { 
  var sheetsTotalParDoc = docs[m].getSheets();

  if (!enTetesCrees) {

      var rowHeadSheet = sheetsTotalParDoc[0];
      var rows = rowHeadSheet.getRange("A1:L1");
      var valuesRowHead = rows.getValues();

      var rowHead = valuesRowHead[0];              

      data = Charts.newDataTable()
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, rowHead[0])
          //.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, rowHead[1])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, rowHead[2])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, rowHead[3])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, rowHead[4])
          //.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, rowHead[5])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, rowHead[6])
          //.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, rowHead[7])
          //.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, rowHead[8])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, rowHead[9])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, rowHead[10])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, rowHead[11])

          enTetesCrees = true;
      /*********************************
      * Fin création en-têtes (colonnes)
      **********************************
      */
    }

  for(var k = 0; k < sheetsTotalParDoc.length; k++) {    

      var sheet = sheetsTotalParDoc[k];   
      var rows = sheet.getDataRange(); //.getRange("A1:L5")
      var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
      var values = rows.getValues();     
    //on commence par la deuxième ligne car la première correspond à l'en-tête
      for (var i = 1; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
        var valuesRow = values[i];


        var rowTraitee = new Array();
        rowTraitee[0] = valuesRow[0];
        rowTraitee[1] = valuesRow[2];
        rowTraitee[2] = valuesRow[3];
        rowTraitee[3] = valuesRow[4];
        rowTraitee[4] = valuesRow[6];
        rowTraitee[5] = valuesRow[9];
        rowTraitee[6] = valuesRow[10];
        rowTraitee[7] = valuesRow[11];

        data.addRow([rowTraitee[0],rowTraitee[1],rowTraitee[2],rowTraitee[3],rowTraitee[4],rowTraitee[5],rowTraitee[6],rowTraitee[7]]);

      }
  } //fin "for" qui parcours chaque feuille d'un spreadsheet

} //fin "for" qui parcours chaque document spreadsheet

  data.build();
```

**Then i tryed to use the GAS filter to filter a column by categories :**

```
      var themeFilter = Charts.newStringFilter()
  .setFilterColumnIndex(5)
  .setMatchType(Charts.MatchType.ANY)
 .setCaseSensitive(true)
  .build();
```

**BUT, there is a problem, the setMatchType(Charts.MatchType.ANY) doesnt work and i dunno why.. it works well on java script option : "matchType" : 'any' ( can i use js on gs ?)
So i decided to build my own filter with chekboxs of differents categories with clickhanlder function to find("string") in the dataTable that i just created before. My problem is , i dont know** how to acces to dataTable's data from a other function(clickhandler-chekbox)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate this problem, and it [appears to be a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11905864/702875). Please file an issue on the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) for updates.